# How can i see git network graph in xp-dev?

Tags: git

I just shifted to new company which uses xp-dev for git.

I have been using gitlab, github and bitbucket, and network graph is quite obvious thing.
But I didn't find it in xp-dev.

Do they even have this thing?

Answer (score 0):

They seem to only have the revision view you can see in [Git Hosting at XP-Dev.com](https://xp-dev.com/features/git-hosting.html)

[image: https://xp-dev.com/images/codebrowser.png]

In that case, your only recourse is to:

- clone the repo
- use one of the commands from "[Pretty git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/6309)"
  (like `git log --color --date-order --graph --oneline --decorate --all`)

Comment: I can use gitk for that as well. But it is really sad that there is no network view.

Comment: @user2025167 I agree. Maybe their support have more to say about the availability of that feature.